# How to fill in columns of table from temporary table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with three columns; two of them are currently filled with NULL values. I have split the first column (which contains data) into two columns that are stored in a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_storage AS (
   select LEFT(column1, POSITION('_' IN column1) - 1), 
          RIGHT(column1, POSITION('_' IN REVERSE(column1)) - 1) 
   FROM table1
);
```

Now I need to take that data and fill in the two empty columns with this data. 
I tried using this:

```
INSERT INTO table1(column2, column3)
SELECT * FROM temp_storage;
```

however this just creates new rows and fills in columns 2 and 3 with this data, leaving column 1 NULL in those rows.

Is there an effective way to fill in the existing rows from the temporary table?

Comment: Look up the difference between `INSERT` and `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're filling in the blank columns from the `column1` in the same row in each case?

Why don't you use `UPDATE`? Then you don't need a temp table.

```
UPDATE table1
SET column2 = LEFT(column1, POSITION('_' IN column1) - 1),
    column3 = RIGHT(column1, POSITION('_' IN REVERSE(column1)) - 1)
```